# Use PHP to iterate over a local HTML file

Tags: php

In PHP I need to iterate over a local HTML file to get the inner HTML and value of the for attribute of labels belonging to  tags with the **selected** class, so the labels for displayname and email in the example below. The HTML is being accessed via direct file access and not through a web browser.

```
<div id="custom_panel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="displayname" class="selected">Public display name</label>
            <input type="text" class="selected" id="displayname" name="displayname" maxlength="254" value=""/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email" class="selected">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="selected" id="email" name="email" maxlength="254" value=""  />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="text" id="age" name="age" maxlength="3" value=""  />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Solution - I updated the label to have the selected class, this simplifies things and means the recommendation to use DOMDocument works well.

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $filename );
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('label');

foreach( $col as $node ) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $node->getAttribute('for') . ' Class: ' . $node->getAttribute('class') . ' Value: ' . $node->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: use `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example of using DOMDocument to load and process an HTML file

```
$filename='c:/wwwroot/somepage.html';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $filename );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach( $col as $node ) {
    echo $node->tagName, $node->nodeValue, '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at PHP DOMDocument [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)